# How to count the number of observations in a SAS table?

Tags: statistics, sas

I am very new to SAS. Now, I have a SAS data table as following:

```
    ID       score
-------------------
    01         1
    02         3
    03         4
    04         2
```

Is there any way to save the number of observations in this table **using only PROC SORT and DATA step**? I want to hold the value in the log window, which is like "hold N=4" in the SAS log script.

Sorry for my unprofessional description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to limit yourself to proc sort and data steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `nobs`= in the set statement.

```
data _null_;
set xyz nobs=nobs;
put "HOLD N=" nobs ;
stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 9):

As a new SAS user, the **NOBS** option may be all you need.  However, as your coding skills increase, you may find yourself in situations where is is not appropriate.  The **NOBS** option on the **SET** statement may not work in all cases.  The value returned will be the number of physical observations in the data set, including any observations that may have been deleted in-place.  It also may not work with certain views (especially views connected to external databases).

The "safest" way to find the number of undeleted observations in a data set or view is to use `PROC SQL` and actually count them, putting the result into a macro variable.  For example, suppose you have a data object named HAVE:

```
proc sql noprint;
   select count(*) into : nobs
   from WORK.HAVE;
quit;
%put 'Obs in data set:' &nobs;
```

Note this works if HAVE is a data set or a view.

Alternatively, if you object is just a data set, you can use the SAS TABLES Dictionary view to return the **NLOBS** attribute, which has the number of "logical" observations (i.e. accounts for any deleted rows):

```
proc sql noprint;
   select nlobs into : nobs
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname='WORK'
    and memname='HAVE';
quit;
%put 'Obs in data set:' &nobs;
```

This will certainly be more efficient if your SAS data set is very large.  I've often wondered why SAS does not make this **NLOBS** value available as an option on the **SET** statement, but I'm sure there are reasons.

PROC SQL, views, macro variables, and in-place deleted observations may be all new to you right now, but as you advance with your SAS learning you are bound to start using them.

Answer (score -2):

data *null*;

set sashelp.vtable;

where libname="WORK" and memname="DS1";

call symput("count_obs",nlobs);

run;

%put obs in ds1 is :&count_obs;

Comment: will be slow if there are lots of tables