# SAS count the number of observations within a by group, after deleting some data

Tags: sas

I have a dataset whose format is similar to the following:

```
| Symbol | Date     | Time | BB | BO | MIDPRICE |
|--------|----------|------|----|----|----------|
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 1    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 2    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 3    | 1  | 3  | 1.5      |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
| FB     | 20130102 | 1    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 2    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 3    | 3  | 5  | 4        |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| FB     | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
```

I am trying to count the number of observations in each by group.

For example, if the dataset is sorted by Symbol, I would like to know how many observations are there for AAPL, FB, etc., respectively. In the above case, there are four observations for AAPL and four observations for FB.

I would like the results be exported to a dataset, and a csv file later (I understand how to export to csv file, so it is not part of this question).

I have been reading materials online. It seems that generally there are two ways. In this [document](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p095-26.pdf), the author says that the nobs might not be accurate, especially if you modified the original dataset in place. Unfortunately, that is the case for me. I deleted some observations using the following code:

```
  data STOCK;
    SET RAWDATA; by SYMBOL;
    /* Delete those with only one observation */
    if MIDPRICE < 3 then delete;
  run;
```

Therefore, according to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612039/how-to-count-the-number-of-observations-in-a-sas-table), the only option left is the sql statement. However, the SQL statement used in the post only count the total number of observations, instead of counting the observations in each by group.

I also thought about counting by incrementing a variable. But it seems that this is a really bad option performance wise.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is any high-performance, while error-proof way of doing this?

The dataset I am operating on is quite large. Usually 30 Terabytes + per dataset, and I have thousands of them to run my code on.

Thank you!

Comment: This shouldn't be a SO question, there are thousands of answers online to answer this question. http://support.sas.com/kb/24/595.html

Comment: http://video.sas.com/detail/videos/how-to-tutorials/video/3306906230001/summary-statistics-using-sas-studio?autoStart=true

Comment: http://support.sas.com/kb/25/279.html

Comment: What's wrong with `proc summary`?

Comment: @Reeza does summary work well with large datasets?

Comment: I would start with a proc freq or means and see what times you get. If they're acceptable, done. If not, then I would look into what server you have and if you have access privileges to run pass through queries. If you can't, I would still consider looking into a hash table count though you may run out of memory. Do you know if your datasets are indexed? If they are that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code in the end:

```
data quotescount;
    set quotes_processed; by Symbol;
    if first.Symbol then count=0;
    count+1;
    if last.Symbol then output;
run;
```

It seems to be the most reliable way, given that SQL query might return [wrong results](http://support.sas.com/kb/54/652.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    create table newtable as
        select symbol, count(*) as cnt
        from stock
        group by symbol;
quit;
```

Comment: Should there be a quit; at the end of the proc sql statement? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: SQL can generate incorrect numbers with a large N. There is a SAS note about this, it may have been corrected for 9.4 but I don't think it was.

Comment: @Reeza . . . I don't believe that note has anything to do with querying a base table.

Comment: I doubt that this data is stored as SAS datasets. They likely reside on a server somewhere. In fact, using Pass Through SQL for datasets of this size may be more efficient, assuming that T+ means 30 trillion rows.

Comment: @Reeza They are stored on a server. How to do a  pass through SQL?